# Use of odbc_exec with successful result downloads PHP page instead of renders is

Tags: php, odbc, centos, freetds, unixodbc

I'm having a very strange issue. I'm using unixODBC with FreeTDS to connect to MSSQL server.

If I perform an SQL command using odbc_exec that results in a valid query, instead of rendering the PHP, I get a prompt to download my php file, which if I accept ends up downloading an empty file.

If I purposefully break my SQL with an improperly formatted statement, the page successfully renders and displays the error statement.

If I use the command line isql to connect to my database and run the query, I am able to get a result on the command line level.

CentOS 5.5 64bit

MSSQL 2005 SP3

unixODBC 2.3.0

FreeTDS 0.82

PHP 5.3.5

Comment: Further investigation yields  [notice] child pid 26273 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you run the page using php on the command line? If its a 64 bit install it may be a result of PHP being built with a different sizeof( SQLLEN ) from unixODBC and or FreeTDS. Was the PHP built against the unixODBC on the machine or installed from a package?